# Memory management with ABAddressBook

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, memory-management

I'm using this piece of code in my app:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *contacts = (NSArray*) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

Am I responsible for releasing both `addressBook` and `contacts`? I've found nothing on the documentation about that...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is the [Core Foundation Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029).  According to the linked document, you own both of those objects.

Here's [an example that uses both of your functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW3).  See how the objects are released with `CFRelease()` at the end.